# How to pass original display property in jquery animation function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I will try to explain the problem as simple as I can:

I have two divs

first div: `<div id="first" style="color:black;"></div>`

second div: `<div id="second" style="color:red;display:inline;"></div>`

I want when I call slideUp on the first div, and it is already hidden, to put all the css style of the second , INCLUDING display property (in first div is block, in second is inline) and only then to show the div.

I tried to do it like this, but then the second display property is lost, and the display property of the first div is restored to block, not inline.

```
$("first").slideUp(function(){ 
    $(this).attr("style","display:none;"+$("second").attr("style"));
    $(this).slideDown();
});
```

Any thoughs how to do it?

Sorry for my english, but I'm from bulgaria and a really need this, becouse is a vital part of a larger project.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: **to put all the css style of the second...** into the first div?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the `.slideDown()` works it displays the element as block.

```
$(this).slideDown(function(){
   $(this).css('display','inline');
});
```

That will make it inline but probably will ruin the animation effect also. It depends

Comment: yes. That is correct. That will going to ruin the animation effect. I need a different solution

Comment: Well inline elements doesn't have `height`, they have `line-height`.
Using `.slideDown()` is based on height so unfortunetly you'll have to re-consider your concept at all

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues. First, you should use jQuery.css to control the styles of your divs. second, to select a div by id, you need to use the CSS "#" symbol:

```
$(this).attr("style", $("#second").attr("style"));
$(this).css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about making a copy of the second element and replacing the text?

```
$("#first").slideUp(function () {
    var content = $(this).text();
    var copy = $("#second").clone();
    $(copy).html("");
    $(copy).text(content);
    $(copy).attr("id", "first");
    $("#first").replaceWith(copy);
    $("#first").slideDown();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmd97/rKejG/19/